# Why this UI-Bootstrap accordion doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying make a page with accordion using UI-Bootstrap.
I found this [example](http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/gj6P5) that is fine for me. So I copied the code in my project but it doesn't works, obviously...

I made this snippet in plunker for a faster [debug](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kimi3vJXHEWbBkwpLPRV?p=preview).

In any case this is the main code:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="main">
          <h3>Doesn't it look better ?</h3>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Why is it better
                </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                    <li>The titles are block, so you don't have to click the text part to activate it</li>
                    <li>Indicators for expand / collapsing items</li>
                    <li>Removed title links' obnoxious :hover underlinings, and outlines.</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` in the plunker. I added the following lines to make it work:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Also, notice your accordion component is not a `ui-bootstrap` accordion.

See **[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DwFzOnQBzZ1o7GjUcsZE?p=preview)**

Comment: You either use core Angular, Angular UI Bootstrap, and Bootstrap CSS, OR you use jQuery, Bootstrap JS, and Bootstrap CSS.  You do not use both.  The former is built on Angular, the latter on jQuery.  Pick your poison, but do not mix.

Answer (score 1):

replace **data-toggle** with **ng-click** and in collapse div add attribute **collapse="!collapseOne"**

for example

```
<a role="button" ng-click="collapseOne = !collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">

<div id="collapseTwo" collapse="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to decide whether or not you want to go the Angular route or the jQuery route.  Don't use both in this case.  The Angular route has you using the Angular UI Bootstrap library and ONLY the Bootstrap CSS file.  The jQuery route has you using jQuery (obviously), the Bootstrap JS library, and the Bootstrap CSS.

Don't mix the two.  If you find that you are, you're doing it wrong.  [Here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) is your accordion demo.

Comment: Yes, I was a little bit confusing about the two accordion types. Ai the end I used Angular UI Bootstrap becouse I need it also for other things. Thank you

Comment: Excellent.  It's a good choice and I'm not just saying that because I'm one of the devs.